# BeanCreationException with nested exception java.lang.LinkageError in IBM websphere 8.0

Tags: java, websphere-8, linkageerror

I was trying to start my application deployed in WAS 8 console. I have seen similar questions like this but not able to understand what solution I have to implement. Please help me with this. I have stuck from long.

server specific class loader policy : multiple
server specific class loading mode : parent first

EAR/WAR class loader policy : multiple
EAR/WAR class loading mode : parent last

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'soapFinsService' defined in class path resource [springcontext/api_third_party_beans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation when resolving method "javax/xml/ws/Service.create(Ljava/net/URL;Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;)Ljavax/xml/ws/Service;" : loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@197001c" of class "org/springframework/remoting/jaxws/LocalJaxWsServiceFactory" and loader "com/ibm/oti/vm/BootstrapClassLoader@753492c" of class "javax/xml/ws/Service" have different types for the method signature
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(SpringContextLoaderListener.java:48)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1649)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:410)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:748)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:633)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:422)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:714)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1134)
```

Answer (score 1):

A LinkageError usually indicates that a class has visibility to two different versions of some class, one directly (through its own class loader) and one indirectly (through some other loader).  This is usually only possible with "parent last"-style loading, so if you don't NEED that, switching the class loading mode might do the trick.  In general, if you don't have a specific reason to use "parent last", it should be avoided, because it messes with default Java class loading behavior and can lead to issues like this one.

Based on the error message, I'd guess that the duplicate-visibility class is the javax.xml.namespace.QName class.  Is there a reason you're packaging an XML API in the application?  WAS has a copy of Xerces packaged in its JDK, so it's unlikely that you actually need to do it unless you have some peculiarity with XML providers.  If you do need "parent last", removing the jar that contains the XML API would also likely resolve the problem.